# Access denied for user 'mgs_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

this is a problem i got when i was trying to run my code:
database: mysql

Error message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mgs_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

this is also the user priviliges, as you can see it's full granted in phpmyadmin
[image]

Comment: Was your user granted access to the database? Are you really connecting from localhost? If this is a remote server, you are probably connecting from whatever your ip happens to be

Comment: yes that user is granted and it's not remote